# comparative study of spoken language complexity or irregularity

Tags: second-lang-acquisition, inflection, irregularity

Could you recommend a publicly accessible study/article that quantitatively compares languages by their complexity or irregularity?

I am interested in spoken languages only. Not writing/spelling.

Number of inflected word forms and number of irregularly inflected words for the most popular languages would be good enough.

Comment: I don't think "complexity" is a meaningful language comparator. Proportion of irregular word forms would be okay though.

Comment: You'd have to sum up the individual topics, but most of what you're looking for is probly in [WALS](http://wals.info/chapter).

Comment: By the usual metrics of irregularity, Dinka is probably the most irregular language. However, outside the population of Dinka speakers, it isn't particularly popular. How far down the list of popularity are you willing to go? I.e. does it need to be in the top 1%, 5%, 10%?